# C++ 64bit, variable not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a problem with my C++ application. It was developed on a 32bit pc, on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, and now I am trying to run it on a 64bit pc.

On my 32bit pc it works fine; on the 64bit pc, Visual Studio does not give any compilation problem, but then on execution gives wrong results.
And I have undestood why.

In the code, I define a variable, of tipe "dag", that is a structure for a direct acyclic graph. By debugging the software, I noticed that, although I declared it, later the software is not able to insert data in it, and the debugger says:

```
CXX0017: Error: symbol "dags" not found
```

Here's my code:

```
    Dag<int64_t>* dags = new Dag<int64_t>();
    dags = getDagsFromRequest2(request, dags);
```

The very strange thing is that, if I follow the flow inside getDagsFromRequest2() function, I can clearly see that dags variable is full of data: on "quickwatch", it shows 2342 nodes inside it. But when I come back from getDagsFromRequest2()  function to this part of the code, debugger says "CXX0017: Error: symbol "dags" not found". How is it possible?

You can also see this screenshot from my Visual Studio debug set.

[image: Debug screenshot]

What could be the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think it's just a problem with the debugging (maybe 'cause of release version), it doesn't affect application behavior.

Comment: You have a possible memory leak there. First you allocate memory to a pointer, then you overwrite the pointer to point to some other memory.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it no it should be in debug. But I think you should only have two options for the build mode - Release and debug(I have never seen a Debug-x64 one). Also aparantly this is a debugger problem as your code compiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities to consider:

1. Running in Release builds. Switch to a Debug build.
2. Using a Debug build that has optimizations enabled and/or debug information disabled. Disable the optimizations and enable the debug information (look in another project for the relevant settings).
3. A corrupt build of some sort. Clean and rebuild the entire solution.
4. Memory corruption which is preventing the debugger from displaying the variable. Ensure that no memory issues exist with a tool like Valgrind.
5. A VS bug. [This report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613569) for VS2010 seems to suggest a known bug with similar characteristics for example. Ensure all patches and hotfixes for VS2008 are installed.

Comment: Thanx Uesp. 1: Just tried, it does not work. 2: How? 3: I've cleaned and rebuilt, but it does not work. 4: How could Valgrind help me? 5: Actually, it could be...

Comment: I'd put my money on this being a bug, there has been a few occasions where I've encountered this (both in C++ and C#)

Comment: If you go into Project-Properties double-check that in your Debug64 build under C/C++ all optimizations are off (/Od) at a minimum. If it is due to memory corruption then Valgrind may be able to detect it. Another option is to log debugging output to the console or file and use a few printf() (or similar) statements. If that works fine then the issue is almost certainly VS.

Comment: @uesp Thanks uesp. I've checked and there's a high probability that is a Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 bug.

Answer (score 1):

The variable dags is defined as your code compiles. The error you see is simply related to the debugger. I am guessing it is caused by running the application in Release mode which sometimes causes confusing and wrong watches values. Try changing the mode to debug(there is a drop down from which you can choose the build mode).

EDIT: as you say you are running in Debug mode, my next guess is that this behavior could be caused by stack corruption. Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect if that is the case. It may take a while to start with it,but it is worth it and will detect if you have some memory corruption.

Comment: Thanx Izomorphius, but I'm on Debug-x64 mode.

Comment: I have added another idea on what could be your problem. I am afraid I can not give many more options without more context.